# Unable to launch native Google Maps within the iOS app - Safari opens instead

Tags: ios, google-maps, url, deep-linking, openurl

I'm having trouble launching a Google Maps app from within the iPhone app. While the app is installed on device, the code launches a Web version of the Google Maps in Safari. On the other hand, Apple Maps native app launches successfully.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
@IBAction func openMap(_ sender: Any) {
  let lat: Double = -37.8218956215849
  let long: Double = 144.9599325656891

  let appleString = "https://maps.apple.com/?daddr=\(lat),\(long)" // Apple Maps - successfully launches an app
  let googleString = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=\(lat)%2C\(long)" // Google Maps - launches a Web version
  let selectedString: String = googleString // Change accordingly
  let url = URL(string: selectedString)!
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

I suppose, the problem is ridiculously simple, however I still haven't figured out how to fix it.

**Update**

Even the Google's example doesn't work on iOS 12 Beta 2:
`https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme`, the issue might be linked with the usage of the Beta software.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme ?

Comment: Is it possible to launch using "Universal cross-platform syntax"? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Comment: It's an error in the iOS 12 beta version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be fixed on last iOS release (12.1.2). And now the following link work on iPhone:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/51.5230369,-0.08225500000003194
```

As alternative solution to /dir api that works on iOs you can use /search :

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query={your_lat},{your_lon}

https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=28.6139,77.2090
```

Comment: Note that the Google's API recommends to use `/maps/search`: [Developer Guide | Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)

Comment: @aloisdg search is ok when you need to show a Pin of a specific location. Direction is used for a little bit different purpose. But both can be adjusted to the final scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Right click on `info.plist` file and select open **Source Code**. Just right below `<dict>` add the following lines and you are good to go!

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Hi Sanket, it seems to be an issue with the beta release of the iOS, not the way I'm constructing the URL. Even the official example doesn't work.